# Enviar uma lista de dados numa viewbag e receber num foreach na view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Os dados da query estão corretos, mas não consigo retornar os dados para a view.

Controlador:

```
var disponib = (from d in db.Disponibilidade
                join c in db.Catequista on d.CatequistaID equals c.CatequistaID
                where c.CatequistaID == d.CatequistaID && d.CatequistaID == id
                select new
                {
                    AnoPastoral = d.AnoPastoral,
                    DiaDisponivel = d.DiaDisponivel,
                    HoraDisponivel = d.HoraDisponivel,
                    HoraFim = d.HoraFim,
                    Observacoes = d.Observacoes,
                }).ToList();

ViewBag.Disponibilidade = disponib;
```

View:

```
@model WebAppCatechesis2.Models.Catequista

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Disponibilidade)
{    
    //  ???
}
```

Comment: Já tentou dar um `cast` na ViewBag? Algo como: `ViewBag.Disponibilidade as ICollection<SUACLASSE>`?

Comment: @MarllonNasser o foreach já faz o cast .

Comment: Alguma solução?

Comment: Você não pode criar uma classe ViewModel que contenha uma classe com uma lista de disponibilidades não? Dessa forma ficaria "mais correto" o fluxo de desenvolvimento. Viewbag talvez não seja a melhor opção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema resolvido com a query**

```
var disponib = (from d in db.Disponibilidade
                            join c in db.Catequista on d.CatequistaID equals c.CatequistaID
                            where c.CatequistaID == d.CatequistaID && d.CatequistaID == id
                            select d);

            ViewBag.Disponibilidade = disponib;
```

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a sua resposta com aceita para poder fechar a questão.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lista = linq.toList<suaClasse>();
ViewBag.MinhaView = lista;


@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MinhaView as IList<suaClasse>) {
   //-- Codigo
}
```

linq = (sua expressão de consulta)

E viável vc colocar antes do foreach uma verificação do tipo:

```
@if(ViewBag.MinhaView != null) {
   //-- foreach aqui
}
```

Não sei sobre sua aplicação, mas há como vc passar um objeto para a view talvez seja ate melhor:

```
return PartialView("NomeDaView", ObjetoDeClasse);
```

na View acessa com

```
@model ObjetoDeClasse

@foreach(var item in Model){ 
   //-- Codigo
}
```

Espero ajudar.